# Resetting Data in an Array If Any Elements Are Equal

Tags: javascript

I've been having an issue with some code in a project I'm doing at school. I have an array of length 4, where each element of the array is an integer. The values of the integers are determined through multiplying Math.random() by the length of another array. The goal of my code is to find some way of checking whether any of the elements are equal to each other, and if they are then I would want to "reset" (redefine) them until they aren't equal. Here's what I just described, albeit in a very basic form:

```
var originalArray=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g];

var or1=Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
var or2=Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
var or3=Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
var or4=Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);

var numArray=[or1, or2, or3, or4];

function resetData(){
  or1=Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
  or2=Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
  or3=Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
  or4=Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
  numArray=[or1, or2, or3, or4];
}
```

I then have another function, at the beginning of which I want to run resetData. However, if any of the elements are equal to each other then I want it to run again until none of them are.

```
function startOperations(){
  resetData();
  //insert other code here
}
```

I'm stuck on what I should do to make it only reset under the previously-mentioned conditions. My initial idea was to do a for-loop, kind of like this:

```
for(i=0; i<songNumArray.length-1; i++){
  if(songNumArray[i]==songNumArray[i+1]){
    resetData();
  }
}
```

But I now realize that this won't work, since this only checks if the elements next to each other are equal. So I tried just an if-statement:

if(songNumArray[0]==songNumArray[1]||songNumArray[0]==songNumArray[2]||songNumArray[0]==songNumArray[3]){
      resetData();
    }

This doesn't work either, of course, which is why I'm here. Does anyone on here have an idea of what I could do?

Comment: you can just use `while` condition

Answer (score 1):

Rather than declaring variables for each element of the array first and putting them into an array later, I'd suggest simply using a array to start with - that way you can use the array methods. You also don't need to reset *all* of the elements in the array and retry until something works - it would be more elegant to try to generate new elements and insert them only if they pass. For example:

```js
function createArrayWithoutDuplicates(highestValMinusOne, length) {
  const highestVal = highestValMinusOne + 1;
  const arr = [];
  while (arr.length < length) {
    let val;
    do {
      val = Math.floor(Math.random() * highestVal);
    } while (arr.includes(val));
    arr.push(val);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(createArrayWithoutDuplicates(10, 7));
console.log(createArrayWithoutDuplicates(10, 7));
console.log(createArrayWithoutDuplicates(10, 7));
console.log(createArrayWithoutDuplicates(10, 7));
console.log(createArrayWithoutDuplicates(10, 7));
console.log(createArrayWithoutDuplicates(10, 7));
```

Comment: Would you mind please [clicking on undeleting this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65388062/what-is-the-regex-form-of-in-the-split-function-in-javascript/65388103#65388103)

Answer (score 0):

Just use another for loop to iterate again. Something like this:

```
for(i=0; i<songNumArray.length; i++){
  for(j=i+1; j<songNumArray.length; j++){
    if(songNumArray[i]==songNumArray[j]){
      resetData();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Set like this to look for duplicates:

```
let dupes;

do {
  let set = new Set();
  dupes = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < songNumArray.length; ++i) {
    if (set.has(songNumArray[i]) {
      resetData();
      dupes = true;
      break;
    }
    else {
      set.add(songNumArray[i]);
    }
  }
} while (dupes);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution seems to do what I wanted! Though apparently my current JavaScript version didn't allow the use of "let", so I had to define them as "var" instead. Still works though!

Answer (score 0):

I would use nested for-loops. That way, we can cross reference all elements of the array with each other.

```
function newData() {
for (var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < originalArray.length; j++) {
        if (i != j && numArray[i] == numArray[j]) {
            console.log('find');
            numArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
            i = 0;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

If you look at the if-statement, you can see I first check to make sure it doesn't equal j, since a number will always equal itself, and we don't want to cross reference the same elements in the array. Next, I check if they're the same. If they are, I set i to 0. This acts similar to recursion, it "resets" or "re-runs" the loop. If a number gets set to an already existing number, it will go through the if statement again, modifying it until it meets the criteria. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 for loops where first one is from first element to second last element and the second loop always starts with the next element that of the first loop and ends with last element of the array.

```
for(i = 0; i < songNumArray.length - 1; i++){
   for(j = i + 1; j < songNumArray.length; j++) {
      if(songNumArray[i] == songNumArray[j]){
          resetData();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a `getUniqueNumber` function that generates a unique number if it's a duplicate.

Commented code below;

```js
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var or1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
var or2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
var or3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
var or4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);

var numArray = [or1, or2, or3, or4];

function getUniqueNumber(index) {
  var val = numArray[index];
  
  // check if subsequent values are equal to current value.
  // if not return current value. 
  // no need to check previous values as they are already unique.
  if (numArray.indexOf(val, index + 1) === -1)
    return val;

  // repeat until unique number is generated
  while (true) {
    val = Math.floor(Math.random() * originalArray.length);
    if (numArray.indexOf(val) === -1)
      return val;
  }
}

function resetData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    numArray[i] = getUniqueNumber(i);
  }
}

function startOperations() {
  console.log("before: " + numArray);
  resetData();
  console.log("after: " + numArray);
  
  //insert other code here
}

startOperations();
```