# What is the regex form of '' in the split function in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace `.split('')` with a regex function resulting the same output

The closest I can think of is `\w` which selects by letter. But the issue here being, split deletes everything being selected.

eg: I have a string `abcd`, performing `.split('')` gives me `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` but `.split(/\w/)` gives me `['', '', '', '']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a zero-width lookahead to make sure there is at least a character ahead:

```js
var s='abcd-123'
console.log( s.split(/(?=.)/) )
//=> [a, b, c, d, -, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really wanted to use a regular expression and split, consume *no* characters in the match, while making sure you're not at the beginning or end of the string, by negative lookaround for `^` and `$`:

```js
console.log(
  'abcd'.split(/(?!^|$)/)
);
```

But if you needed to solve this with a regex, consider using `.match` instead, I think the intent is a lot clearer:

```js
console.log(
  'abcd'.match(/[\s\S]/g)
);
```

Comment: Even shorter: `'abcd'.match(/./g)`